# как разделить шаблон на части в Angular 2 + / изменить шаблон без пересборки проекта

Tags: angular2, angular4, angular5

для редактирования дизайна и разметки независящих друг от друга частей хочу разделить шаблон на части.

как это сделать подскажите?

например у меня есть шаблон компонента xxx с таким содержимым:

```
<div class="header">
 <li class="list" *ngFor="let ob of objects1">{{ ob }}</li>
</div>
<div class="navigation">...</div>
<div *ngIf="somelogick | async">Loading...</div>
<ul *ngIf="!somelogick | async">
  <li class="list" *ngFor="let ob of objects2">{{ ob }}</li>
</ul>
```

в данном примере objects1 и objects2 загружаются через http api что занимает лишние секунды во время правок верстки и дизайна.

Я сделал компонент "tester" и хотел бы указать в templateUrl как раз кусочек шаблона сверху, какой содержит только *ngFor ( li class="list" ) указав при этом готовые данные в objects2

это правда не избавит меня от сборки проекта при каждом чихе.
подскажите если есть какие то другие способы верстки шаблонов ангуляра в каких не 
участвует webpack?
Я понимаю что там webpack но просто не верю что для того чтоб поиграть с шрифтами надо сборку ждать каждый раз, какая частенько еще и запускаться не хочет

Comment: Что вы подразумеваете под разделением шаблона на части? Создания разных компонентов?

Comment: нет не компонентов. сейчас учточню

Answer (score 0):

Вероятно автор вопроса хотел разбить шаблон *.html компонента Angular на несколько, но это невозможно. 
Эту проблему необходимо решать созданием дочерних компонентов и обвязывать их ч/з EventEmitter (при необходимости пробрасывания значений или вызова событий)